# Unshelve a shelveset from one branch to another in Visual Studio 2022 using TFS

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, tfs, visual-studio-2022, tfvc

I have created a shelve set working on a wrong branch. There are quite some changes and now i wanted to see if I can somehow migrate that change to the target branch. The source and target branch are in same workspace.

When I undo all pending changes from source and target, Take the latest and try to unshelve from the shelveset. It gets applied to the source (wrong) branch itself. There is no option to select the target branch.

I tried Team Foundation Server Power Tools it's not supported with VS 2022. Is there any way to achieve this OR is rework the only way?

I tried

```
tfpt unshelve /migrate /source:"$Source" /target:"$target" "shelvesetname"
```

It says the `tfpt` is not recognized, as it's not compatible with VS 2022

Comment: Check the similar [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747848/tfpt-exe-on-visual-studio-2017). You could try the extension [MultiMerge.2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Jesusfan.MultiMerge2022&ssr=false#overview) and the guide is [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Jesusfan.MultiMerge2017).

Comment: Hi @BaijuChandran, may i know if there's any update? The tools works on my side. let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: The last version of Team Foundation Server Power Tools with tfpt is [Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2015Power) for Visual Studio 2015. I believe the power tools installer checks if VS2015 is installed.

Comment: Hi, Yes I tried with the MultiMerge.2022. so I tried to merge the shelveset to a different branch. and what it did was just created a new folder in the target branch with the shelveset changes. Because Of the urgency I had to do the rework. My expectation was it  should show as if the target branch has those changes, when I unshelve and then I test and check IN to the target branch.